# Not possible to increase number of threads in Julia

Tags: multithreading, julia

I changed the number of threads to 4 following the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.2/manual/parallel-computing/#Setup-1). I know that the maximum number of threads is limited by `Sys.CPU_THREADS` which is 8 in my case. But I can't change it to 8. Why is this?

What I am doing:
set `JULIA_NUM_THREADS=8` in cmd

There shows no error, but in Julia I still have `Threads.nthreads() = 4`

Comment: What have you tried and how have you verified that it's not working? Please show the exact commands you execute and their output.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Added it

Comment: and do you start julia from within the cmd window in which you executed that statement?

Comment: @JoachimSauer No I am using Atom (JuliaPro). Like my post above says, it easily worked with 4 Threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Atom you can set the number of threads in the settings of the *julia-client* package (see screenshot). The default is set to `number of cores` which would probably be the four you are experiencing.

[image]